# Can we skip indexes when we search a string in another string?

Tags: string, search

Considering a search in a string for an exact match of another string. Is it safe to continue the search at the position where a partial match stopped to match, without getting wrong results?

In code:

```
int indexOf(string target, string search){
    for(int i=0; i + search.length < target.length; i++){
        int f=0;
        for(; f < search.length && search[f] == target[i + f]; f++); //empty loop
        if(f == search.length) return i;

        i += f;  //is it safe to do this without to worry about a missing match? 
    }
}
```

The thing to worry about is to miss an exact match starting in the partial match (somewhere between i and i + f in the code above). But in fact I couldn't think up any example case to proof the worry. Can you?

Comment: Yes, you need to worry about it, and an example would be searching for "ananas" in the string "anananas".

Comment: OK - re-posted comment as an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to worry about it, and an example of why you need to worry about it would be searching for the substring "ananas" in the string "anananas".

Answer (score 1):

There are various string search algorithms [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).

I think this is what you want which is know as [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).